# SKView's Background colour overwrites SKSpriteNode's colour after adding Texture in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, colors, sprite, chess

I am writing an IOS app for chess programming using SpriteKit in Swift. While adding texture of a chess piece to an existing coloured SKSpriteNode, the SKView's background colour overwrites the SKSpriteNode's background colour.

Every chessboard square is an SKSpriteNode with Green or White colour. The expected behaviour is to retain the SKSpriteNode's colour(Green or White) in the chess board square even after adding a texture (chess piece) on top of the chess board square. (i.e) The texture's background colour must dynamically match the chessboard square's current colour (Green or White).

SKView's background colour is set to browncolor
`backgroundColor = SKColor.brownColor()`

SKSpriteNode for chessboard squares (green and white squares) created inside nested loop.
`boardSquare.square = SKSpriteNode(color: currentColor, size: boardSquare.squareSize)`

Code to add optional chess piece texture. getPieceTexture returns optional SKTexture? for the initial square positions.
`boardSquare.square.texture = getPieceTexture(boardSquare)`

I could not find a way to get past the issue I mentioned in the beginning. I have also attached a screenshot of the chess board which shows, Chessboard squares, Chess Pieces and SKView's background colour. Can somebody please help me get a solution for this issue?

Kindly excuse me if there are any errors in this post. This is my first post.

Thanks,
ArtBajji

[Partial screenshot of the ChessBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/662qH.png)

Comment: I could not solve this issue, but got past this. Created a new SKSpriteNode with the piece texture and placed the new node in the same position as the Chess board square node. The background colour of the Chess board square did not change to SKView's background colour but remained same as the square's colour. Hope this helps others facing similar issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Created a new SKSpriteNode with the piece texture and placed the new node in the same position as the Chess board square node. The background colour of the Chess board square did not change to SKView's background colour but remained same as the square's colour. Hope this helps others facing similar issues. Thanks.